# Concatenating Variables within Powershell

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell

I'm trying to concatenate two variables within Powershell to form a complete file path and file name to save a text file.

I have two variables

- $Log_path and
- $Log_name

I'm trying to join the two variables together within this piece of code:

> $objWorkbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open $Log_path"\ $Log_name"

I'm unable to find the correct combination of functions??

A "\" is also required to be added between the Log_path and Log_name variables to correctly format the file path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Join-Path](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849799.aspx) and it will put in the directory slash for you.

```
$objWorkbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open (Join-Path $Log_path $Log_name)
```

It handles the logic if $Log_Path parent already has or doesn't have the slash.

```
>join-path c:\temp test.txt
c:\temp\test.txt

>join-path c:\temp\ text.txt
c:\temp\test.txt
```

Answer (score 13):

```
$path = "C:\folder"
$name = "file.exe"
$fullname = $path + "\" + $name
$fullname
```

*(or)*

```
$fullname = "$path\$name"
```

*but not*

```
$fullname = '$path\$name'
```

Output

> C:\folder\file.exe